Will this operation increase the vertex connectivity?
Let $G$ be a graph with the following properties:

$G$ has connectivity $k$;
$G$ has a unique minimum vertex cut $S$ (of size $k$).

If we add a new vertex $s$ to $G$ and connect it to at least $k$ vertices in $G$, including at least one vertex from each $S_i$, will the resulting graph have connectivity $k+1$ ?
Note that the condition of uniqueness of $S$ cannot be omitted, as demonstrated in the following example. The vertex $u$ is not a unique vertex cut of $G$. By adding $s$ and some edges as described above, $v$ remains a vertex cut in the resulting graph $G'$. Therefore, the connectivity does not increase.

This question is a generalized form of a detail from one of my own project. I'm not sure if it is correct.

If $t \le k$, it's possible that the neighbors of $s$ are a smaller vertex cut.

Yes. we need to add a condition $t>k$.

A $k$-cut of $G'$ must have all the vertices of $G$ on the same side of the cut, otherwise, it would induce a $k$-cut in $G$ (or $(k-1)$-cut if $s$ belongs to the cut), and it can't be the unique $k$-cut since it is no longer a cut in $G'$.
The only possibility is that the cut leaves $s$ isolated, but then the cut must contains the neighbourhood of $s$, which is greater than $k$.
